# Trying to find complete string values from one file based on another file using AWK

Tags: awk, read

Hello I have 2 files with the first file containing a few values for example

```
powershell
vectormaps
JuniperSA
```

and the second file containing values and and ID

```
appid uid
SplunkforSnort 340
powershell 610
vectormaps 729
JuniperSA 826
postfix 933
SplunkforJuniperSRX 929
TA-barracuda_webfilter 952
TA-dragon-ips 954
dhcpd 392
```

So im trying to run a while loop with AWK to get the values and their corresponding ID's but the output file seems to be writing something else. This is how im trying to run the while loop.

```
while read $line;
do
awk '/'$line'/ {print $0}' file2.csv > new
done < file1
```

My expected output should be

```
powershell 610
vectormaps 729
JuniperSA 826
```

but my output is

```
appid uid
SplunkforSnort 340
powershell 610
vectormaps 729
JuniperSA 826
postfix 933
SplunkforJuniperSRX 929
TA-barracuda_webfilter 952
TA-dragon-ips 954
dhcpd 392
```

it seems as if nothing is happening. What am i missing here?

Comment: is `awk` mandatory ? what's wrong with `grep -f pattern list` ?

Comment: are pattern in pattern file clean ? no trailling space, tab, not windows edited file ?

Comment: actually grep also did the job. but once the file gets more complicated i was wondering if i could use advaced features of awk. Thats why.

Comment: @Archemar you can't do this task robustly with just grep. `grep -f pattern list`, for example, would falsely match substrings and strings containing regexp metachars and strings in the wrong column and there aren't options to grep to let you modify the call to grep to say "only match a literal string in the first column".

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}; $1 in a' file1 file2` should work.  The command is taken from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670688/469418) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670691/469418).

Comment: I would use `join` here. That’s what it is built for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {$(NF+1)=a[$1]}1' file2 file1
powershell 610
vectormaps 729
JuniperSA 826
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: `{print $0, a[$1]}` would be a bit more efficient than `{$(NF+1)=a[$1]}1` since the former just prints the 2 strings while the latter additionally modifies a field which causes awk to have to rebuild $0 from the fields, replacing every FS with OFS. It MAY also cause awk to have to resplit the record into fields again too as adding a field modifies the record, I'm not sure about that one.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there is no reason to use a `while` loop or `awk` regardless of how complicated the file might become. You are simply looking to print lines in the second file that contain strings from the first file. It's best to use the KISS approach rather than complicating something where it isn't necessary.

The following will do what you want:

```
grep -f file1 file2.csv
```

Comment: That would falsely match substrings and strings containing regexp metachars and strings in the wrong column. You can't robustly do this task with just grep.

Comment: That is the example that was given and it's been confirmed that it does what is wanted.. If there are other circumstances, then what I gave can be modified. I'm not going to attempt to provide something that accounts for every possible scenario because nothing does. Requiring such a thing would render a substantial majority of the answers here useless.

Comment: I understand it's what was given, often as in this case the OP doesn't think of problem cases and just provides some sunny day data. Given different input it'd fail. [@HatLess' awk answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711457/133219) will work robustly for any input containing substrings, metachars, matches in the wrong column, etc., while the grep command cannot be modified to do so (without adding additional commands like sed to pre-process the data). Using awk for this is just all round the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

When setting a variable in shell you must not use the $ sign. Additionally awk can't user shell variables, you have to pass them to awk with `-v variable=value`

```
while read line;
do 
awk -v line="$line" -e '{if  ($1 ~ line) print $0} ' file2.csv
done < file1 >new
```

Comment: this is a very good approach. Thanks. I didnt know about that -v.

Comment: @ranjitabraham, no, this is a well known anti-pattern (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and has additional issues including exposing the shell variable to globbing, word splitting, filename expansion, and will do a partial regexp match across a whole line while you need a full word literal string match against 1 column. It'll also produce just 1 line of output in `new` instead of many.

Comment: It's doing the same as `grep -f file1 file2.csv` but orders of magnitude slower and with multiple additional issues. If you copy/paste it into http://shellcheck,.net I expect it'll tell you about some I haven't mentioned yet as well as some I have.

Comment: Right, the redirection to file `new` was at the wrong place. Corrected it. I wanted to give an answer as close to the original question as possible.  `grep` is the right tool for this, but maybe it can't be used in this case?

Comment: Right, you can't do this with just grep, of the mandatory POSIX tools awk is the right one for this.

Comment: The expression `($1 == line)` would be better because this would not match `vectormapsi`.